# Make arbitrary normal subgroup be the kernel of some homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I come up with the following conjecture when solving some exercise in abstract algebra. Let $G$ be a group, and $N\lhd G$. Is it always true that there exist a homomorphism $f:G\to G$ such that $\ker f=N$?

Comment: Not if N is an additive subgroup of the integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Consider $G = \mathbb{Q}$ (with addition) and $N = \mathbb{Z}$. Since $G$ is abelian, every subgroup of $G$ is normal, so we know $N$ is normal. Now suppose there is some homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ with $\ker\phi = \mathbb{Z}$. Then $\phi(\frac{1}{2})$ must be such that $\phi(\frac{1}{2})+\phi(\frac{1}{2})=\phi(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}) = \phi(1) = 0$. But the only $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfying $x+x = 0$ is $x=0$, so $\frac{1}{2} \in \ker\phi$, so $\ker\phi \neq \mathbb{Z}$.

However, as John Hughes hinted in the comments, you can always find some other group $H$ and a homomorphism $\phi: G \to H$ such that $\ker\phi = N$. The converse is true to: if you have a homomorphism $\phi: G \to H$, you know $\ker\phi$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.